# Showing entries based on URl segment and relationship

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, relationships, url

I have a timetable of agenda times in a channel called "agenda" with a relationship to "events"

I'm trying to control which agenda times show using the URL, but no events show up. In "agenda" you pick 1 "event" to be related with.

I want only the agenda items from "my-event" if it is the 3rd segment to show.

Thanks in advance for any help pointing me in the right direction.

```
  {exp:channel:entries channel="agenda" orderby="date" sort="asc"   } 

{if agenda_event:url_title == segment_3}

    <tr>
      <td>{agenda_start format="%g:%i"}</td>
      <td>{title}</td>
      <td>{agenda_speakers}<a href="{path='speakers/bio/{agenda_speakers:url_title}'}">{if agenda_speakers:speaker_intro != ""}{agenda_speakers:speaker_intro}{/if} {agenda_speakers:speaker_first_name} {agenda_speakers:speaker_last_name}{if agenda_speakers:speaker_outro != ""},{agenda_speakers:speaker_outro}{/if}</a>{/agenda_speakers}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
{/if}



      {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: What do you get when you just output `{agenda_event:url_title}` ?

Comment: Nothing. Unfortunately. If i put dynamic="no" then I get all the results

Comment: Try putting the out put of `{agenda_event:url_title}` inside of your conditional. Do you then only get the url_titles you are looking for?

Comment: Not sure I follow in the code example isn't inside?

Comment: Try this: `{if agenda_event:url_title == segment_3}{agenda_event:url_title}<br>{/if}`. Do you get a list of `url_title`s that you want? Make sure this is inside of your `{exp:channel:entries}` loop. Also, could you please expand your question to include some example URLs and the wanted output for those URLs?

Comment: If it helps the URLs typically are like this "events/agenda/event-name-goes-here" and when I post no event it shows everything, yet it looks like the segments ans ulr_titles match